# Separate email messages are being combined

Tags: php, database, email, mysqli

I am trying to send emails using PHP using data from a database. The issue I am having is that the emails are being combined for each subsequent result match.
So if I have 3 users that have the same match criteria, Yes/Yes for example, the first email is clean, the 2nd email contains the contents of the first then second email and the third recipient contains the first, second then third. I am not sure why it is combining messages, but obviously would like it to stop. :-)

```
<?php
$servername = "intentionally empty";
$username = "intentionally empty";
$password = "intentionally empty";
$dbname = "intentionally empty";
$tblname = "intentionally empty";
$email_to = "";
$email_subject = "";
$email_message = "";
$email_from = "";

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Unable to Connect to '$dbhost' - Please email support@domain.com");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tblname WHERE Active='Yes' AND Reqested='Yes'";
    $result = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);
    if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
    {
        echo "Error: " . mysqli_query_error();
    }

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $first_name = $row['First'];
        $last_name = $row['Last'];
        $dob = $row['DOB'];
        $variableA = $row['VarA'];
        $variableB = $row['VarB'];
        $email_to = $row['Email'];

    $email_from = "support@domain.com"; 
    $email_subject = "Reminder: Requested information for $dob - $varA";
    $email_intro .= "Hello $first_name $last_name,\n";
    $email_intro .= "\n";
    $email_intro .= "This is your monthly request reminder that for $dob - $varA\n";
    $email_intro .= "\n";
    $email_var .= "If you have already sent your updates then you can disregard.\n";
        $email_end .= "\n";
    $email_end .= "Please let us know if you have any question.\n";
    $email_end .= "\n";
    $email_end .= "Thank you,\n";
    $email_end .= "Management.\n";

    $email_message .= "$email_intro$email_var$email_end";

// create email headers
if (@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, 'From:' . $email_from));

echo 'Email sent to: ' . $email_to. '<br>';

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post Successfully Email sent message you can reinitialize or set the value of variable `$email_message as Null`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Any idea why before the loop vs after successful script changes things?

Comment: @Kevin, when you use `string operators` for a variable. It will contain the whole text until you make it null again. So in the code you have submitted, after sending a mail, it does not set the variable value null, and keeps previous data which later add with new data and so on

Comment: @Imran Adbur Rahim, thanks. I understood that, but I was wondering why setting to null after Success message works, but setting to null/'' before the loop didn't work? Purely for curiosity at this point since it is functioning correctly.

Comment: not only ` after Success message` , you can set it null just after the loop start. 
Matter is, when it enter into the loop, it doesn't use previous anything ( if it dosent get  the command to use ).
It actually not only the loop, when programs run, they dont execute previous code until they get command for previous code ( previous code which is already executed)

Answer (score 2):

You're not resetting your `$email_message` or `$email_intro` variables at the start of the loop. Add

```
$email_message = $email_intro = '';
```

at the top of your `while()` loop, and it'll clear for each iteration.

Comment: So the line above while()?
I had that before with the same issue. Just tried it, and put all variables in that line, with the same result. First email is fine, subsequent ones are combined/jumbled.

Comment: Email is now more jumbled than just stacked. Email 1 is normal. Email two has $email_intro for first recipient, then $email_intro for 2nd recipient, $email_var, then same order for $email_end

Comment: A bit late, but I meant to add it as the first line _inside_ the loop. Work the code through in your head - if you only reset the variables before the looping starts, then each iteration will make a successively longer and longer email, since you're always adding new text to the intro and messages. You need to set them back to null (or an empty string) after each successive iteration - this can either be at the top or bottom of the loop, but it needs to happen inside it.